# Implicit differentiation- tangent line horizontal

Tags: calculus

Find all points on $xy=e^{xy}$ where the tangent line is horizontal.

a) $(0,1)$

b) $(0,0)$

c) $(1,0)$

d) none of the above

The only problem is that the derivative $dy/dx= -y/x$ is 0 at two points and picking both of those points isn't really an option.

Comment: The set of points $(x,y)$ verifying the condition is empty.

Comment: Because C cannot yield the same answer on both sides- I get it. Can you also help me answer this one? What is the equation of the tangent line to the curve x^2+y^2=25 at the point (0,-5)? x=5, x=-5, y=5, y=-5.

Comment: Can someone please help me with the problem in the comments? Thanks! I think the answer is y=-5.

Comment: Try to make a drawing of the set (a circle) and plot the point. What does the tangent look like?

Answer (score 2):

There are no values $t\in {\mathbb R}$ for which $t=e^t$. So the set is empty. Option (d)

Comment: Right.  But he just needs to check that none of the three points listed satisfy the equation.

Answer (score 1):

If indeed $dy/dx=-y/x$, then the derivative is undefined at the points $(0,1)$ and $(0,0)$. This leaves only (c) as an option, which works.

EDIT: However, I believe your derivative is incorrect. Try again, using product and chain rules.

Comment: I checked it using a derivative calculator from Wolfram Alpha and Symbolab, and both yield the same derivative: -y/x. Can you check too?

Comment: the derivative is really irrelevant, see HH Rugh's answer

Answer (score 0):

Define the function:

$F(x, y(x))=xy-e^{xy}$

By definition we know that $F(x, y(x))=0,\ \forall (x,y)$.

Now you can calculate the derivative of function $F$ thinking to $y$ as function of $x$:

$F'(x, y(x))=y+xy'-\left[e^{xy}(y+xy')\right]$.

By definition $F=0$; so we can say that $F'=0$, so we have:

$y+xy'-\left[e^{xy}(y+xy')\right]=0$.

Make some calculations;

$y+xy'-ye^{xy}-xy'e^{xy}=0$

Collect $y'$ and $x$ and solve by $y'$:

$xy'(1-e^{xy})=y(e^{xy}-1)$; so:

$-xy'=y$

The unique point for which $y'=0$ is $(x,y)=(1,0)$

Edit: As stated by  H. H. Rugh above, no point is acceptable.

Hope this help.

Comment: Yes, the derivative of the function is indeed dy/dx=-y/x.

Comment: but the point $(1,0)$ does not even satisfy the original equation.

Comment: yes, I get it now.

Comment: Right ! in these problems often i forget to check what really counts. Sigh.

Comment: What about the case $e^{xy}-1=0$?